# calculate/sum ##percent of the RGB Color?

Tags: javascript, c#, php, html, openxml

I would like calculate/sum ##percent of the RGB Color, like calculate 20%, 25%........ of the Color in any program or logic?

For Example: I had applied some X color in table cells in winword

```
Cell 1: 100 % X Color;
Cell 2: 25% of X Color;
Cell 3: 75% of X Color;
```

then, I saved the docx as html, the td cell background generated as:

```
Cell 1: #00B0F0; (rgb 0, 176, 240);
Cell 2: #DDEEFB; (rgb 221, 238, 251);
Cell 3: #5ABCF2; (rgb 90, 188, 242);
```

here, My question is "how to calculate percentage from RGB color to RGB Color in the X color?", I cannot see relationship is (RGB) * (255/100 * %), My client prefer exact hex value of color in XML.

Here, I attached the docx screen shot of the docx [image]

Comment: `$color = rgb(255, 255, 128); $red = 255/255*100; $green = 255/255*100; $blue = 128/255*100;`?

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick reply, what is the logic?, can you get me 25% of the #00B0F0; (rgb 0, 176, 240)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question or what you're trying to do. I you would like to get 25% of rgb(0,176,240) shouldn't this be rgb(0,44,60) i.e multiply each component with `0.25`?